# Problem of white space

Tags: page-numbering

I am creating my thesis for my master degree,and i am new to latex
In my latex try to do page numbering acording to the chaper.It worked but white space pop up. not worked `\clearpage` or  `\raggedbottom` for the issue of white space..what i need to do..other all are correct...sample code is,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=5em]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[font=bf,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
% \rfoot{\thepage}
% \pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}


\pagestyle{fancy}
 \lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\bfseries Chapter1.      INTRODUCTION }
\lfoot{unix chicargo}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
% \thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\captionsetup{}

\begin{center}
\chapter { Chapter 1 \hspace{0.5cm} INTRODUCTION}
\end{center}

\section{ secone}

\subsection{subsec1}
\begin{figure}[ht]
   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.5cm]{images_ch1/dd.jpg}
   \end{center}
\begin{center}
\caption[dd]{ ddd}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
....
...
....
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you just want to omit the page number on chapter headings?

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear from your question which white space you want changing, but some comments on the code, fixing these may perhaps address the issue.

```
\rhead{\bfseries Chapter1.      INTRODUCTION }
```

You never want to put fixed texts in the head like this, or fixed numbers, LaTeX will automatically number chapters and place the chapter title in the heading.

```
\begin{center}
\chapter { Chapter 1 \hspace{0.5cm} INTRODUCTION}
\end{center}
```

Don't use `center` around a chapter or section heading, it will not section the heading and it introduces unwanted vertical space. The formatting of the chapter and section headings is set up by your document class, you can change it but you should never change it with explicit font and spacing commands in the actual heading. Again LaTex will number teh chapters automatically so you should not put a fixed number in the title. All three of those lines  should simply be

```
\chapter {INTRODUCTION}





\begin{figure}[ht]
   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.5cm]{images_ch1/dd.jpg}
   \end{center}
\begin{center}
\caption[dd]{ ddd}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Again don't try to center captions by surrounding them by `center` the formatting of captions is set by the documentclass (and customised in your case by the `caption` package.

It is better to use `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}` to center a graphic as `center` introduces additional vertical white space which you probably don't want here.

Comment: yaa..it's worked....

Comment: yaa..it's worked.... thank u very much                                                         But i need to center the chapter like , "Chapter 2  Title of Chapter" (in one row)...so what i need to do?     I used \usepackage{sectsty} and \chapterfont{\centering} then it centered ,but with two rows(1st row "chapter1" & 2nd row "title of chapter") so what is a solution for that?                          plz help again for that issue...                                    thank u...

Comment: The default chapter heading layout in report class places Chapter and number above the title, you can redefine`\@makechapterhead` or use a package that helps with that, ask another question on site if not clear as discussing code in comments doesn't work, teh default definition is `\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}`

Comment: I add \def\@makechapterhead#1 , then align left both chapter & title of it..But i need to center both chapter and it's title within one row...what i need to use? thnk u..

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101502/chapter-number-and-title-in-one-row