# chapter number and title in one row

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I need to add both the chapter number and the title in one row with centering: something like "Chapter 2 Title of Chapter".

My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=5em]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

\section{ sec1}

....................

\subsection{subsec1}

..................

\end{document}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button ({}) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titlesec` package allows you to customise the appearance of titles.

EDIT: I updated my solution based on Gonzalo Medina's comment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\titleformat{\chapter}
{\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter} {0.5em} {}


\begin{document}
  \chapter{First chapter}

    \lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to add it as  "Chapter 1  FIRST CHAPTER"  not like "1 First chapter".( Chapter 1 need to be display)